# Swift Range behaving like NSRange and not including endIndex

Tags: swift

I ran across some funky `Range` behavior and now I'm questioning everything I thought I knew about `Range` in Swift.

```
let range = Range<Int>(start: 0, end: 2)
print(range.count) // Prints 2
```

Since `Range` uses a `start` & `end` instead of a `location` & `length` that `NSRange` uses I would expect the range above to have a count of 3. It almost seems like it is being treated like an `NSRange` since a count of 2 makes sense if your `location = 0` and `length = 2`.

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
let slice = array[range]
```

I would expect `slice` to contain `ABC` since range's end index is 2, but `slice` actually contains `AB`, which does correspond to the `range.count == 2`, but doesn't add up since the range's `endIndex == 2` which should include `C`.

What am I missing here?

I'm using Xcode 7.2's version of Swift, not any of the open source versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range objects `Range<T>` in Swift are, by default, presented as a half-open interval `[start,end)`, i.e. `start..<end` (see [HalfOpenInterval](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/HalfOpenInterval/) `IntervalType`).

You can see this if your print your `range` variable

```
let range = Range<Int>(start: 0, end: 2)
print(range) // 0..<2
```

Also, as Leo Dabus pointed out below (thanks!), you can simplify the declaration of `Range<Int>` by using the half-open range operator `..<` directly:

```
let range = 0..<2
print(range) // 0..<2  (naturally)
```

Likewise, you can declare `Range<Int>` ranges using the closed range operator `...`

```
let range = 0...1
print(range) // 0..<2
```

And we see, interestingly (in context of the question), that this again verifies that the default representation of Ranges are by means of the half-open operator.

---

That the half-open interval is default for `Range` is written somewhat implicitly, in text, in the [language reference for range](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/type/Range/):

> Like other collections, a *range containing one element has an **endIndex
>   that is the successor of its startIndex***; and an empty range has
>   startIndex == endIndex.

`Range` conforms, however, to `CollectionType` protocol. In [the language reference to the latter](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/s:PSs14CollectionType), it's stated clearly that the `startIndex` and `endIndex` defines a half-open interval:

> The sequence view of the elements is identical to the collection view.
>   In other words, the following code binds the same series of values to
>   x as does for x in self {}:
>
> ```
> for i in startIndex..<endIndex {
>     let x = self[i]
> }
> ```

To wrap it up; `Range` is defined as half-open interval (`startIndex ..< endIndex`), even if it's somewhat obscure to find in the docs.

---

See also

- [Swift Language Guide - Basic Operators - Range Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

> Swift includes two range operators, which are shortcuts for expressing
>   a range of values.
>
> ...
>
> The closed range operator (a...b) defines a range that runs from a to
>   b, and includes the values a and b. The value of a must not be greater
>   than b.
>
> ...
>
> The half-open range operator (a..< b) defines a range that runs from a
>   to b, but does not include b. It is said to be half-open because it
>   contains its first value, but not its final value.

Comment: I don't see anything in the `Range` docs that indicate that it is a closed-open interval. Is it just me or does the `(start: T, end: T)` syntax indicate that it would include the end index?

Comment: It isn't very clear, but it is in the language ref for `Range`. See edit in 1 min.

Comment: Answer updated to point you to the relevant parts of the reference docs.

Comment: @LeoDabus I thought that was already quite clear from the above, but perhaps I should've mentioned that assignment method explicitly? Thanks for pointing that out (but please use some additional words next to code comments next time, so I know whether it's critics or just a hint for some cool stuff! :)  )

Comment: @dfri yes please go ahead I think you should mention that he can simplify range<Int> declaration simply doing it like this

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't want to simplify range declaration any more. I feel that the `a...b` & `a..<b` syntax is too short and unclear as to what is happening. It just seems like having only a 1 character difference between the two is not enough to prevent mistakes. Especially since there is no whitespace around the relevant character it is easy for it to blend in. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @jamone thats is totally personnel, specially if you need to use it as it is done in a for loop for i in startIndex..<endIndex. Imagine that like this  for loop for i in Range<Int>(start: 0, end: 2). or in another context where you are not just initialising a var

Comment: BTW 0..<2 it is just a shorter way to use instead of using for the last index count - 1 our count.predecessor()